# IoT Hub message payload - how to define Application Properties and Body?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

What is needed to define / create Application Properties in a message sent to the IoT hub?

I have one demo device, where I create the message using the **C client SDK** and everything works fine. Those incoming messages can be routed based on **Application Property** values and the **EventData** parameter is set correctly in an Azure Function that listens on the IoT Hub.

Another device is also sending data to the same IoT hub. Code running on this device is developed directly by my customer, but I doubt that they used the SDK. Instead I assume they create the whole payload themselves.

To me the **incoming JSON** looks basically the same, like the one built with the SDK. It contains a section for ***applicationProperties*** and one for the ***body***.

```
{
  "applicationProperties": {
    "type": "telemetry",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "body": {
    "device_id": "sensor1",
    "datetime": "2019-05-09T10:44:04Z",
    "channels": {
      "T": 24.42,
      "H": 44.87,
      "C": 1234
    }
  }
}
```

But it turns out, that the **message** as a **whole** is treated as the **body**.

So why does this message behave different? What needs to be done, to tell IoT Hub what are application properties and what is the *real* body when not using the SDK?

Comment: have a look the following links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax and for direct MQTT protocol: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device

Comment: Are you using the MQTT protocol directly?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I guess they are connecting using MQTT directly. Need to clearify with the customer, which will need some days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of using the MQTT protocol directly, the application and system properties are part of the **topic**, see the following example:

```
devices/Device1/messages/events/location=abcd&$.to=deviceABC
```

the output telemetry message received by Visual Studio 2019 Cloud Explorer:

```
[Monitor D2C Message] [5/9/2019 7:54:40 AM] Message received on partition 2:{"counter":17,"time":"2019-05-09T14:54:40.1984163Z","deviceId":"Device1","windSpeed":9.1991,"temperature":14.88,"humidity":81.66}
Application properties:
  location: abcd
System properties:
  iothub-connection-device-id: Device1
  iothub-connection-auth-method: {"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}
  iothub-connection-auth-generation-id: 636550937738557556
  iothub-enqueuedtime: 5/9/2019 2:54:38 PM
  iothub-message-source: Telemetry
  x-opt-sequence-number: 13069
  x-opt-offset: 5989280
  x-opt-enqueued-time: 5/9/2019 2:54:38 PM
  EnqueuedTimeUtc: 5/9/2019 2:54:38 PM
  SequenceNumber: 13069
  Offset: 5989280
  to: deviceABC
```

In the case of using the connection less protocol such as Https, the application and system properties are part of the **headers**. The following example shows the above properties from the MQTT protocol:

```
iothub-app-location:abcd
iothub-to:deviceABC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turned out, that the customer used Node Red for device implementation. But obviously the Node for the IoT Hub doesn't support application properties. 
I accepted your answer because it led me into the right direction anyways.